# Using Kafka with Elastic search

Tags: search, indexing, relational-database, apache-kafka, distributed-computing

I'am working  with myself , I' am using orcal database ,I want to index the data from  orcal data base into elastic search, the problem is how to get the updated and new rows from orcal data base into elastic search without  reindex the whole Table data?
is Kafka as messaging Queue suitable for this situation ?